# Java Maven javacv error : org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException

Tags: java, maven, opencv, javacv

I set javacv on maven but I get error like this :

> org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an
>   error: 1 (Exit value: 1)  at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:764)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:711)
>     at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:289)   at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)    at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

here is the maven code:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>tesseract</artifactId>
        <version>3.04-1.1</version>
    </dependency>  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>leptonica</artifactId>
        <version>1.72-1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2-0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Please add more information.. How have you called Maven? What kind of configuration have you done? Which version of Java, Maven etc. do you use? A full log output would be helpful.

Comment: You could do some basic checks on your maven installation- are you able to build a very simple project? (let say, no dependencies, and a single "hello world" class only).